# How to print character every time after a loop is completed

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I'm having problems printing the below pattern and don't know how to solve it.

Note: Must use for and while loop.

I'm trying to achieve pattern like:

```
0
1
####
2
3
####
4
5
####
```

But I'm getting:

```
0
1
####
1
2
####
2
3
####
3
4
####
```

Code I'm using is:

```
n = 0
for z in range(10):
    while n < 2:
        print(z)
        z += 1
        n += 1
    print("####")
    n = 0
```

Comment: Try this change - `for z in range(1, 11):` and see what's difference first...

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because in `z += 1` you're assuming that you're changing the value of z in `for z in range(10):`, but in this for loop the value of z in each iteration is the next sequence in the list of [0,1,2,3,4], so it discards the `z += 1` operation you did, so it repeats the number after the `#####`.

a solution to this problem would be doing something like this, check if n is 2 in an if statement and don't change the value of z:

```
n = 0
for z in range(10):
    print(z)
    n += 1
    if (n==2):
        print("####")
        n = 0
```

this would print:

```
0
1
####
2
3
####
4
5
####
6
7
####
8
9
####
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop. You can chose either `while` or `for`

Version with `while`:

```
n = 0
while n < 6:
    print(n)
    print(n+1)
    print('####')
    n += 2
```

Version with `for`:

```
for n in range(0, 6, 2):
    print(n)
    print(n+1)
    print('####')
```

If really you want to use two loops (might be useful if you want to print series of more than 2 numbers in between the ####):

```
for n in range(0, 6, 2):
    for z in range(2):
        print(n+z)
    print('####')
```

output:

```
0
1
####
2
3
####
4
5
####
```

Comment: The way you is explained is detailed and easy understand to me.

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because z is taking the value in range() every time the with loop finishes. mozway is right, however I think n should start at 1:

```
n = 1
while n < 6:
    print(n)
    print(n+1)
    print('####')
    n += 2
```

Comment: Why? the expected output shows 0 as a starting point

Comment: True, I misread it!